# Cosmos Finding Duplicates

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have written the following Query to find Duplicates.

```
SELECT s.count, s.ID 
FROM (
    SELECT c.ID, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM c
    GROUP BY c.ID
) s
WHERE s.count > 1
```

When I run it the initial time via the portal it might return 700 ID's and if I run it again it returns 710 ID's.  The table is static and there is no applications writing to it.

What am I doing wrong or what do I not understand about CosmosDB.

Any comments is appreciated.

Comment: Is portal - probably continuation token not being followed

Comment: Does it give you an option to view more results? I doubt that it will as continuation tokens are documented as unavailable for `group by` queries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#continuation-tokens - so you may just be seeing whatever it can fit in before hitting some sort of limit (for RU or time)